# Cast item to be type of received parametar

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have method for filtering a generic list

```
public bool FilterRecords(object obj)
    {
        Type ss = obj.GetType();
        var item = obj as (obj.GetType());
        .
        .
        .
        return false;
    }
```

Object *obj* can be *Customer, Order, Artical*, etc. Problem is that `var item = obj as (obj.GetType());` does not work. I tried some more options, but I run out of ideas. How can I cast item to be type of object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you even need to do this?  Once you cast it to a type that isn't known until run time what exactly would you do with it?  It's not like you can then write code to call the members of the type without using reflection.

Comment: You cannot define the target type for cast operations on run-time. However, you can change your method to a generic one - FilterRecords<T>(object obj) - and then can test with "as" if the parameter passed is of type T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed one option. Hence I have my class with generic parameter , I just set

```
var item = (T)o;
```

it works and there is no need for *Type ss = obj.GetType();*.

Comment: If you are going to use generic type parameters, maybe you could consider: `public bool FilterRecords<T>(T obj)`, then there is no need for a cast.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of options, you could do something like:

```cs
public bool FilterRecords(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Customer) 
    {
        var customer = (Customer)obj;
        //... 
    }
    else if(obj is Order)
    {
        var order = (Order)obj;
        //... 
    }
    //... 
}
```

But this probably indicates a bad design, and a need for class inheritance and polymorphism.